# Collect to a TreeMap in one line using Collator

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors, collator

I have the following piece of code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public final class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Object[][] pairs = { { "Arka Gdynia", Collections.emptyList() },
                { "Legia Warszawa", Collections.emptyList() }, { "ŁKS Łódź", Collections.emptyList() },
                { "Śląsk Wrocław", Collections.emptyList() }, { "Wisła Kraków", Collections.emptyList() }, };

        final Map<String, Object> clubPlayerMap = Arrays.stream(pairs)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(c -> c[0].toString(), c -> c[1], (o1, o2) -> o1, TreeMap::new));
        for (final String key : clubPlayerMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key);
        }
    }
}
```

This unfortunately does not produce the result I want. The keys need to be sorted according to Polish collation.

```
Arka Gdynia
Legia Warszawa
Wisła Kraków
ŁKS Łódź
Śląsk Wrocław
```

The result I expect is

```
Arka Gdynia
Legia Warszawa
ŁKS Łódź
Śląsk Wrocław
Wisła Kraków
```

So I googled and found a way to do this with `java.text.Collator`. I am wondering however whether it is possible to do it as one-liner together with `stream()` and `collect()`.

The solution I came up with is the following, but unfortunately it is not very neat.

```
import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public final class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Object[][] pairs = { { "Arka Gdynia", Collections.emptyList() },
                { "Legia Warszawa", Collections.emptyList() }, { "ŁKS Łódź", Collections.emptyList() },
                { "Śląsk Wrocław", Collections.emptyList() }, { "Wisła Kraków", Collections.emptyList() }, };

        final Map<String, Object> clubPlayerMapCollated = new TreeMap<>(Collator.getInstance(new Locale("pl", "PL")));
        final Map<String, Object> clubPlayerMap = Arrays.stream(pairs)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(c -> c[0].toString(), c -> c[1], (o1, o2) -> o1, TreeMap::new));
        clubPlayerMapCollated.putAll(clubPlayerMap);
        for (final String key : clubPlayerMapCollated.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Is it at all possible to produce the map from a one-liner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing a method reference to the default constructor (`TreeMap::new`), pass a lambda expression that would generate the desired `TreeMap`:

```
final Map<String, Object> clubPlayerMap = 
    Arrays.stream(pairs)
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(c -> c[0].toString(), 
                                    c -> c[1], 
                                    (o1, o2) -> o1, 
                                    () -> new TreeMap<>(Collator.getInstance(new Locale("pl", "PL")))));
```